# Check if a user was "active" in multiple rows - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I go about creating group_ids in the following example based on the area(s) the users are active in?

```
group_id   rep_id   area   datebegin   dateend
1          1000     A      1/1/15      1/1/16
1          1000     B      1/1/15      1/1/16
2          1000     C      1/2/16      12/31/99
```

In the table you can see that rep 1000 was active in both A and B between 1/15 and 1/16. How would I go about coding the group_id field to group by datebegin & dateend?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you also post the expected result?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, the expected result is the table I posted, sorry, should've mentioned that. Everything in the table above exists at this moment besides group_id. What I posted is what it should look like.

Comment: So, you essentially want to produce `group_id`?

Comment: can you have overlapping intervals? if so, how should the groups look like?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos. Yes

Comment: @vkp, groups can overlap. Someone could be in A for a time, A & B, for a time, and then B. Ideally any change would create a new group_id, the only time a group_id would ever be the same was if the begin and end dates are a perfect match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to assign groups. As you said, only if the date_begin and date_end exactly match for 2 rows, they would be in the same group. Else a new group starts.

```
select rep_id,area,date_begin,date_end,
,case when @repid <> rep_id then @rn:=1 --reset the group to 1 when rep_id changes
      when @repid=rep_id and @begin=date_begin and @end=date_end then @rn:=@rn --if rep_id,date_begin and date_end match use the same @rn previously assigned
 else @rn:=@rn+1 --else increment @rn by 1
 end as group_id
,@begin:=date_begin
,@end:=date_end
,@repid:=rep_id
from t
cross join (select @rn:=0,@begin:='',@end:='',@repid:=-1) r
order by rep_id,date_begin,date_end
```

The above query includes variables in the output. To only get the `group_id` use

```
select rep_id,area,date_begin,date_end,group_id
from (
select rep_id,area,date_begin,date_end
,case when @repid <> rep_id then @rn:=1
      when @repid=rep_id and @begin=date_begin and @end=date_end then @rn:=@rn 
 else @rn:=@rn+1 
 end as group_id
,@begin:=date_begin
,@end:=date_end
,@repid:=rep_id
from t
cross join (select @rn:=0,@begin:='',@end:='',@repid:=-1) r
order by rep_id,date_begin,date_end
) x
```

Comment: Works great! I had to tweak a single line to get it to run correctly; the comma after "from t," I changed to a cross join. Thank you for your help.

Comment: also make sure the starting `@repid` value `-1` isn't a value from the rep_id column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables in order to enumerate groups of records having identical `rep_id, datebegin, dateend` values:

```
SELECT rep_id, datebegin, dateend,
       @rn := IF(@rep_id <> rep_id, 
                 IF(@rep_id := rep_id, 1, 1),
                 @rn + 1) AS rn
FROM (       
   SELECT rep_id, datebegin, dateend
   FROM mytable 
   GROUP BY rep_id, datebegin, dateend) AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rep_id := 0, @rn := 0) AS v   
ORDER BY rep_id, datebegin
```

**Output:**

```
rep_id, datebegin,  dateend,    rn
-----------------------------------
1000,   2015-01-01, 2016-01-01, 1
1000,   2016-02-01, 2099-12-03, 2
```

You can use the above query as a derived table and join back to the original table. `rn` field is the `group_id` field you are looking for.